# dimissing keyboard after use in a ui collection view controller

Tags: swift, keyboard

I am trying to remove the keyboard in my ui collection view controller after it pops up from using the search bar which is located in the navigation bar

If I have an amount of cells (say 7 cells) that is larger than the screen i can dismiss the keyboard using

```
collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag 
collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

though if i only have two cells populated thus not allowing for any scrolling to see cells further down the screen i cannot use

```
 collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag 
collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

what other options do i have ? I have played around with tap gestures also though to no avail

Comment: enable cancel button for search bar and on cancel you can use resignfirstResponder = true or view.endEditing(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling:

`collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true`

This enables scrolling even with less items than the screen size.

Comment: Thanks Dejan, Its works perfectly , have a good day or night as it is here in Australia

Comment: @benpalmer661 You should accept this answer. If it’s solved your problem.